# event hubs receive slow

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am testing Azure event hubs from a single machine.

I have an event hub with max allowed partitions (32).

What I have found is that writing to the hub is very fast - basically in the order of 1000 msgs / sec. However when I try to pull the data out, I don't get nearly the same throughput. Pulling out 1000 msgs takes something like a minute.

I have tried both the Direct approach with 32 parallel receivers and the EventHost approach. Both are roughly the same in terms of speed.

I have left all settings as default.

Is it because I am using a single machine for pulling the data out? Note that writing from the same machine is not a problem.

Update: Here is the code that I am using for pulling data from Event Hubs (direct version):

```
let startDirectPump
    stream
    eventHubConnectionString
    storageConnectionString
    fPost =
    let tag = "startEventHubPump"
    let client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(eventHubConnectionString,stream)
    let cg = client.GetDefaultConsumerGroup()
    let runtimeInfo = client.GetRuntimeInformation()
    let pCount = runtimeInfo.PartitionCount
    let receivers =
        [for p in 0..pCount - 1 ->
            cg.CreateReceiver(runtimeInfo.PartitionIds.[p],System.DateTime.UtcNow)
            ]
    let tasks =
        receivers
        |> List.map (fun r ->
            async {
                try 
                    while not r.IsClosed do
                        let! e = r.ReceiveAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                        if e <> null then
                            fPost e
                with ex ->
                    do! Async.Sleep 5000
                    Logging.logex "eh receive" ex
            })
    tasks |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.Start
    client
```

Comment: were you able to resolve it? I ran into the same issue as yours, I'm using a python SDK

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to pump data into Storm, there is actually integration being done to provide an adapter for getting EventHub data into Storm. Please see code @ https://github.com/hdinsight/hdinsight-storm-examples/tree/master/lib

As for figuring out the latency problem there is a number of things you may want to try:

- Enable ServiceBus performance counter to see the receive latency. You can follow the example @ https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Messaging-7a0a0761
- Your code is using DateTimeUtc as the checkpoint marker. I wonder if you can try using offset as the marker instead to see if there is a perf improvement (using datetime as marker will require a translation on the service side).
- Make sure your client is running at the same Azure region as the EventHub.

Thanks
-Eric Lam (MSFT)

Answer (score 0):

what are you using to measure the speed? Are you storing the data in database and checking there if all the data has been received? This problem may be somewhere else, may be in your database insertion. Some time it takes time when it tries to take lease on partitions initially. You can try sending more message once it warmed up. And check if still takes the same time.

Comment: I am using the wall clock for now. The difference is clearly noticeable. For now I am just dumping messages to the console as simple strings. I don't believe that this would be the bottleneck. I will run a longer test to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I have not looked under the covers but could it be that the throughput is limited because of a single AMQP connection / single machine. Don't know if 32 partitions means that 32 connections are opened - one for each partition?

Comment: @fwaris, Have you figure out the root cause for this?

Comment: We faced similar kind of issue. Network latency could be a culprit here. You can try with 'short messages'. Another way could to to try out in Azure environment, like running your code on a worker role.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to determine the root cause. The messages are very short (about 200 char json). I don't believe that network latency is an issue as we are on the corporate network. Also tried Azure site.

At this point, my belief is that to get higher throughput you have to use multiple concurrent connections possibly from different machines. We may have to look for alternatives such as Kafka to get around this issue.

Comment: That should not be the case. We are working on similar kind of piece. We can easily receive 1000 msg per small messages. In case of bigger message, we could not receive them in this pace. But when we tested on Azure worker role, our receiving rate increased dramatically. Of course, it cannot go beyond 2 MB per second in case you are using 1 throughput unit.

Comment: thanks for info. I have tried azure website - not a worker role - but did not see any substantial increase. The code is very straightforward so not sure where the issue lies. Our goal is to pump data into Apache Storm so for now are using web sockets directly.

Comment: thanks i will try apache kafka, I do not like hearing about slow cloud latency, but it doesn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same approach as you did and couldn't receive any events / data. After some time, I found about [EventProcessorHost](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/) which is a bit more verbose, but works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

increasing the throughput unit will help you .